# how we can convert vb script into javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

How can I convert a VB script into Javascript?

I want to convert

```
top.HeaderFrame.postForm() 
top.parent.BodyFrame.Expand()
```

into Javascript.

Comment: Can you paste the sourcecode of this Methods?

Comment: javascript equivalent not convert

Comment: Seems to me that JavaScript would be quite happy with those constructs